# Passing a mobile number from a CSV with spaces as a param to Jmeter HTTP GET request

Tags: jmeter

New to Jmeter, I want to pass a variable of say "1234 567 8910" from a CSV file as a Param value to a HTTP GET request and I just can't seem to get it to work, tried a number of ways, any ideas ?

Complains with "java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 71" which is the first space in the param.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the csv file.....

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass this phone number as a GET request parameter just tick `URL Encode?` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

If you need to pass this phone number as a part of a GET request URL path - you can use [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) to wrap your variable from the CSV file:

```
${__urlencode(${variableFromCSV})}
```

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.